# If I require jquery over jquery_ujs, my application breaks and vice versa

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I need to require both in my application.js file. The problem is if one is above another, parts of my application break. But I need both of them working.

E.G. If I require jquery over jquery_ujs, my log out functionality stops working and I receive a `No route matches [DELETE] "/users/sign_out"` error.

E.G. Vice Versa, if jquery_ujs is over jquery, some links from devise such as 'destroy' or 'edit' completely disappear.

I believe this to be a problem with devise, but I am unsure what I should do.

Application.js:

```
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require masonry/jquery.masonry
//= require_tree .
```

_header.html.erb:

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
      <% if user_signed_in? %>
      <li><%= link_to "New Pin", new_pin_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Account Settings", edit_user_registration_path %></li> 
      <li><%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li> 
      <% else %>
      <li><%= link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path %></li>
      <% end %>
  </ul>
```

Update: Obviously, when I logout, it doesn't work and gives the error `No route matches [DELETE] "/users/sign_out`. However, if I refresh the page I get a successful logout :/ everytime.

Comment: Can you put the way you call the sign_out. Link for the sign_out please. And also jquery should be called on top of jquery_ujs.

Comment: Yes, have added :)

Answer (score 4):

it seems like you are adding jquery_ujs before jquery. so you need to add jquery first something like

```
//= require jquery   
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require masonry/jquery.masonry
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: It still doesn't change much. Just gives different problem.

Comment: @Benjamints: Please let us know what is error If error is related to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, paste this code into `devise.rb`

```
config.sign_out_via = :get
```